# Can anyone give me example how to create new IBM Connections Activity using xPages Social Enabler?

Tags: xpages

Can anyone give me an example how to create new IBM Connections Activity using xPages Social Enabler? I cant find any usefull info in documentation so I have adapted an example from Niklas Heidloff on how to create a new bookmark in Connections. I have the following code for creating a new activity:

```
try { 
   var svc = new sbt.ConnectionsService("/activities/service/atom2/activities"); 

   var sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder(); 
   sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); 
   sb.append("<entry xmlns:snx=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn\" xmlns:opensearch=\"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/\" xmlns:thr=\"http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">"); 
   sb.append("<title type=\"text\">"); 
   sb.append("test activity from xpages"); 
   sb.append("</title>"); 
   sb.append("<content type=\"html\">"); 
   sb.append("</content>"); 
   sb.append("</entry>");                 

   var msg = svc.post(null, sb.toString(), "xml"); 
} catch(e) { 
    print(e) 
}
```

But code above do not create anything but raises error on Domino console. This is returned by svc.post() command:

```
[31726:00075-3041917840] 11/19/2012 01:03:59 PM  HTTP JVM: Client service request to: http://vhost1279.site1.compute.ihost.com:81/activities/service/atom2/activities did not return OK status. Status returned: 415, reason: Unsupported Media Type, expected:information, please consult error-l 

[31726:00075-3041917840] 11/19/2012 01:03:59 PM  HTTP JVM: g-0.xml located in /local/opt/ibm/lotus/notesdata/domino/workspace/logs 

[31726:00075-3041917840] 11/19/2012 01:03:59 PM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sbt.services.client.ClientServicesException: HTTP Status 415, Unsupported Media Type. HTTP error response code received in response to request to url: http://vhost1279.site1.comties/service/atom2/activities
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to use it properly or point me to some usefull documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!  I looked to source and problem was obvious. This is rather a bug or at least misconception  but can be easily resolved . According the docs and my testing proves this Connections requires the following header in request: Content-Type = application/atom+xml  .... but in source code of Social Enabler I found these two related methods:

protected void prepareRequest(HttpClient httpClient, HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase, Options options) throws ClientServicesException {
            // TODO: add support for gzip content
            //httpClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

```
        if(options.getHeaders()!=null) {
            addHeaders(httpClient, httpRequestBase, options);
        }
        if (options.content != null) {
            String contentType = null;
            HttpEntity entity = null;
            Object content = options.content;
            try {
                //If a subclass overrides com.ibm.xsp.extlib.services.client.Service.processRequestContent(HttpRequestBase, Object, Options)
                //the the subclass must set the content type of the request, and also set the request's entity!
                if(processRequestContent(httpClient, httpRequestBase, options)){
                    if (content instanceof IValue) {
                        JsonFactory jsFactory = new JsonJavaScriptFactory(DesignerRuntime.getJSContext());
                        entity = new StringEntity(JsonGenerator.toJson(jsFactory, content, true));
                        contentType = "application/json";
                    }
                    else if (content instanceof JsonObject) {
                        JsonFactory jsFactory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
                        entity = new StringEntity(JsonGenerator.toJson(jsFactory, content, true));
                        contentType = "application/json";
                    }
                    else if (content instanceof Node) {
                        entity = new StringEntity(DOMUtil.getXMLString((Node) content, true));
                        contentType = "application/xml";
                    }
                    else {
                        entity = new StringEntity(content.toString());
                        contentType = findRequestTextContentType(options);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if(ex instanceof ClientServicesException) {
                    throw (ClientServicesException)ex;
                }
                throw new ClientServicesException(ex, "Error while parsing request content");
            }
            if (entity != null && (httpRequestBase instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase)) {
                httpRequestBase.setHeader("Content-type", contentType);
                ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) httpRequestBase).setEntity(entity);
            }
        }
    }

protected String findRequestTextContentType(Options options) {
        return "text/plain";
    }
```

As you can see there is no such header (application/atom+xml) for any case. But if you provide XML content as string, the code uses the 'findRequestTextContentType' method to return a default content type, which is 'text/plain' that is not correct for our situation. It is hardcoded so there is no way how to setup the default encoding. But, at least, the 'findRequestTextContentType' is type protected so it can be overriden. So I have created my own ConnectionsService class that extends the former one and overrides the findRequestTextContentType method to return correct content type for my case. And this works fine and resolved the problem !!

```
import sbt.ConnectionsService;

public class ConnectionsServiceCustom extends ConnectionsService {

    public ConnectionsServiceTcl(String serviceUrl) {
        super(serviceUrl);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     @Override
     protected String findRequestTextContentType(Options options) {
            return "application/atom+xml";
        }

}
```

Comment: David, id you follow my advice and create an XML Node then condition <code>content instanceof Node</code> is triggered and you are good. While it looks easy creating "XML Strings" will bite you sooner than later, so "kick the habit" and use SAX or DOM and a Node ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a StringBuilder to create XML. At least use [SAX](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8B3G7U) or better [Apache Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org/) for creating XML ([Tutorial here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-atompp3/)). This ensures that your XML is valid and in case of Abdera also valid ATOM.

**It is important** to use this approach, since you get a `Node` object in return, that automatically triggers the needed content type.

Then check how to [create](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus+Connections+3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_activities_lc3&content=pdcontent) an Activity in the [Connections documentation wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus+Connections+3+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Lotus_Connections_API_overview_lc3&content=pdcontent) (yes - confusing). In [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/connections-deploy-pt6/) you find the code to retrieve an activity - I actually recommend to use [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to get the valid format as an example. Some CURL URLs are [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+3.0.1+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_started_ic301&content=pdcontent). The closest you get to a full example is Luis' demo of a [status update](http://www.lbenitez.com/2009/11/updating-your-lotus-connections.html).

To explore connections I use the following batch file:

```
set server=[server] 
set HOME=c:\work
curl %server%%1 –-netrc -G --basic -k -v -L -o %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7
```

with an .netrc file (see the [CURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html))

```
 machine [server] login [user] password [password]
```

This is the XML format you need for an activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> 
   <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="activity" label="Activity"/> 
   <title type="text">Posted activity</title> 
   <content type="html"> 
  This is an activity that has been automatically uploaded from the cURL command line
   </content> 
</entry>
```

And post it like this:

```
post activities/service/atom2/activities newactivity.xml activityresult.xml
```

Open the activityresult.xml and locate ocate the href attribute of the app:collection element - you need it to add actions. Use the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn"> 
   <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="todo"/> 
   <category term="Connection4.0"/> 
   <category term="Test"/> 
   <title type="text">Some things that need to be done</title> 
   <content type="html"> 
This is an &lt;b&gt;action&lt;/b&gt; in an activity that has been automatically uploaded from the cURL command line.
   </content> 
   <snx:assignedto>noreply@ibm.com</snx:assignedto> 
</entry>
```

and this command:

```
post [the-url-you-found-above] newaction.xml actionresult.xml
```

Once the CURL version works you can try yourself using Abdera code.

Comment: I have looked to Luis Benites code and he uses client.addCredentials("http://connections.tap.ibm.com", null, null, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)); ... one have to know users password to authenticate against Connections? But we dont know users passwords stored in Domino person documents.  We use SSO with Domino and Connections server.

Comment: Then you need to use the LTPA Token. Abdera use under the hood the Apache HTTP Client where you can set a cookie. You need to read the LTPAToken from the browser session

Comment: Did STEP 1 with manually posting an activity work? It is important that you keep the problems separated :-)

Comment: I tried using cUrl, cUrl authenticates correctly but returns this error from Connections server:
<error xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
  <code></code>
  <message>com.ibm.openactivities.atom.exception.ParsingException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.</message>
  <displaymessage></displaymessage>
  <errortype></errortype>

  <trace>com.ibm.openactivities.exception.OpenActivitiesException: com.ibm.openactivities.atom.exception.ParsingException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.</trace>
</error>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample from REST client in Firefox:

https://vhost1279.site1.compute.ihost.com/activities/service/atom2/activities

Header: Content-Type application/atom+xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="activity" label="Activity" />
<content type="html"/>
<title type="text">
test
</title>
</entry>
```

The problem with the code above is that you pass in a String to the post method. That however doesn't set the right content type. Please use APIs Stephan suggests to create a org.w3c.dom.Node with the XML and pass this in instead. This will set automatically the right content type in the header.

Comment: I'm posting to this URL: https://vhost1279.site1.compute.ihost.com/activities/service/atom2/activities ... as http redirects to this SSL version.

Answer (score 0):

As Niklas and Stephen point out you need to use a Dom object (Node, Document etc).. If you are getting an error when creating such an object then it is most likely because the contents of the document/node is poorly formatted or incorrect.. 
There is a built in XPages util class that allows you to create documents from strings

`com.ibm.commons.xml.DOMUtil`

Check out

```
com.ibm.commons.xml.DOMUtil.createDocument(String, String)
```

e.g.

```
com.ibm.commons.xml.DOMUtil.createDocument("my xml string", null);
```

The first parameter is the contents of the XML document, the second is the format.

This class provides several utility methods for parsing and constructing DOM documents.